# YouTube видео не открывается в полный экран в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

Встроить код сюда не получилось. Google не отдает работоспособный `iframe`.

Смысл таков, что я динамически создаю `pop-up` из `JavaScript` в котором `iframe`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var link = $("#rotation_banners a").attr('href');
  if (typeof link !== 'undefined' && link.match(/(youtube.com)/)) {
    $("#rotation_banners a").YouTubePopUp();
  }
  if ($(".youtube").length > 0) {
    $(".youtube").YouTubePopUp();
  }
});

/*
 Name: YouTubePopUp
 Description: jQuery plugin to display YouTube or Vimeo video in PopUp, responsive and retina, easy to use.
 Version: 1.0.1
 Plugin URL: http://wp-time.com/youtube-popup-jquery-plugin/
 Written By: Qassim Hassan
 Updated By: Makarenko Ivan
 Twitter: @QQQHZ
 Websites: wp-time.com | qass.im | wp-plugins.in
 Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 Copyright (c) 2016 - Qassim Hassan

 Updated: 2016.06.25
 Updated by: Ivan Makarenko
 Description: Add supporting of other links to youtube video, and more settings
 See: more settings https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru
*/
var auto_close = true;
var ik_player;
//this function is called by the API
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(playerid) {
  playerid = 'youtube-iframe';
  ik_player = new YT.Player(playerid, {
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == '0' && auto_close) {
    // destroy pop-up
    $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap').addClass('YouTubePopUp-Hide').delay(515).queue(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
}

(function($) {

  $.fn.YouTubePopUp = function(options) {
    // include YouTubeAPI
    if ($("script[src^='//www.youtube.com/player_api']").length === 0) {
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
      $("head").append(s);
    }

    // turn off auto close on complete
    // and remove from options because not iframe option
    if (options !== undefined && options.autoclose !== undefined) {
      if (options.autoclose === 0) {
        auto_close = false;
      }
      delete options.autoclose;
    }
    var YouTubePopUpOptions = $.extend({
      autoplay: 1,
      rel: 0, // show relevant video after play? (1|0) if 0 auto close after end of playing
      enablejsapi: 1, // access to use YouTube JS API (1|0)
      showinfo: 0, // show title and author info (1|0)
      playerapiid: 'youtube-iframe',
      v: 3,
    }, options);

    $(this).on('click', function(e) {

      // get youtube link from data or from href
      var youtubeLink = $(this).data('youtube-link');
      if (typeof youtubeLink == 'undefined') {
        youtubeLink = $(this).attr('href');
      }

      // default aspect ratio is 4 by 3 but if set data full-wide is true then 16 by 9
      var aspectRatio = $(this).data('aspect-ratio');
      if (aspectRatio == '4by3') {
        aspectRatio = 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3';
      } else {
        aspectRatio = 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9';
      }

      var split_c, split_n;
      if (youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com)/)) {
        split_c = 'v=';
        split_n = 1;
      }

      if (youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com\/embed\/)/)) {
        split_c = 'embed/';
        split_n = 1;
      }

      if (youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com\/v\/)/)) {
        split_c = 'youtube.com/v/';
        split_n = 1;
      }

      if (youtubeLink.match(/(youtu.be)/) || youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[0-9]/)) {
        split_c = '/';
        split_n = 3;
      }

      if (youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[a-zA-Z]/)) {
        split_c = '/';
        split_n = 5;
      }

      var getYouTubeVideoID = youtubeLink.split(split_c)[split_n];

      var cleanVideoID = getYouTubeVideoID.replace(/(&)+(.*)/, '');

      var videoEmbedLink = '',
        count = 0,
        key;
      if (youtubeLink.match(/(youtu.be)/) || youtubeLink.match(/(youtube.com)/)) {
        videoEmbedLink = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + cleanVideoID + '';
        // add settings
        count = 0;
        for (key in YouTubePopUpOptions) {
          if (count < 1) {
            videoEmbedLink += '?';
          } else {
            videoEmbedLink += '&';
          }
          videoEmbedLink += key + '=' + YouTubePopUpOptions[key] + '';
          count++;
        }
      }

      if (youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[0-9]/) || youtubeLink.match(/(vimeo.com\/)+[a-zA-Z]/)) {
        videoEmbedLink = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + cleanVideoID + '';
        // add settings
        count = 0;
        for (key in YouTubePopUpOptions) {
          if (count < 1) {
            videoEmbedLink += '?';
          } else {
            videoEmbedLink += '&';
          }
          videoEmbedLink += key + '=' + YouTubePopUpOptions[key] + '';
          count++;
        }
      }

      // append pop-up
      $('body').append('<div class="YouTubePopUp-Wrap"><div class="YouTubePopUp-Content"><div class="' + aspectRatio + '"><span class="YouTubePopUp-Close"></span><iframe id="youtube-iframe" src="' + videoEmbedLink + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div></div>');

      $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap, .YouTubePopUp-Close').click(function() {
        $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap').addClass('YouTubePopUp-Hide').delay(515).queue(function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      });

      onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
      e.preventDefault();

    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {

      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('.YouTubePopUp-Wrap, .YouTubePopUp-Close').click();
      }

    });
  };

}(jQuery));
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/*
    Name: YouTubePopUp
    Description: jQuery plugin to display YouTube video in PopUp, responsive and retina, easy to use.
    Version: 1.0.1
    Plugin URL: http://wp-time.com/youtube-popup-jquery-plugin/
    Written By: Qassim Hassan
 Updated By: Makarenko Ivan
    Twitter: @QQQHZ
    Websites: wp-time.com | qass.im | wp-plugins.in
    Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
        http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
        http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
    Copyright (c) 2016 - Qassim Hassan
*/

.YouTubePopUp-Wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999999999999;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: YouTubePopUp;
  animation-name: YouTubePopUp;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  .YouTubePopUp-Content {
    max-width: 680px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    .embed-responsive {
      overflow: visible;
      &.embed-responsive-4by3 {
        margin-top: 12.5%;
      }
      &.embed-responsive-16by9 {
        margin-top: 21.875%;
      }
    }
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes YouTubePopUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes YouTubePopUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.YouTubePopUp-Hide {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: YouTubePopUpHide;
  animation-name: YouTubePopUpHide;
}
@-webkit-keyframes YouTubePopUpHide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes YouTubePopUpHide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.YouTubePopUp-Close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../img/youtube-close.png) no-repeat 50% 50% black;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  -webkit-background-size: 24px 24px;
  -moz-background-size: 24px 24px;
  -o-background-size: 24px 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 999;
  &: hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 710px) {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="YouTubePopUp-Wrap">
  <div class="YouTubePopUp-Content">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><span class="YouTubePopUp-Close"></span>
      <iframe id="youtube-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KT0XROBxiq8?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;playerapiid=youtube-iframe&amp;v=3" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но в браузере **Google Chrome**, при нажатии на кнопку открыть в полный экран открывает не видео, а страницу сайта. Все настройки сброшены на по умолчанию. ***Версия: 49.0.2623.112***

Comment: Вы хотите показывать рекламу в полный экран?

Comment: @KoVadim Нет. Само видео, вместо видео отображается страница сайта, без рамок браузера.